# Success is always fired even when the response is an error

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have an Ajax function that takes in 4 parameters. The url, the data, the success callback and error callback functions. I'm trying to make this Ajax function as reusable as possible. Here's how it looks:

```
function send_data(url, data, successCallback, errorCallback) {
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: 'post',
        data: data,
        success: successCallback,
        error: errorCallback
    });
}
```

Where the success callback looks like this:

```
function createMessage(message) {
   console.log(message);
}
```

and error callback looks like this:

```
function createErrorMessage(message) {
   console.log(message);
}
```

However, when I call the Ajax function with parameters that should return a 400 error bad request, the success function is always fired regardless if it is a 200 or 400 response. I don't understand why the success callback function is firing when only the error function should be firing. **However, both are firing.** Why is this?

Comment: Is it possible to provide a [minimal, verifiable, and complete example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in a codesandbox or in code snippet ("<>" button) here that reproduces your output/bug?

Comment: if you are returning json response on server side then you need to include `dataType: json` as ajax parameter

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in these lines

```
success: successCallback,
        error: errorCallback
```

They both are running immediately one after the other so both are returning their values.
 Make an anonymous callback function on both success and error and it will work fine.

```
success: function() {
    successCallback();
},
error: function() {
    errorCallback();
}
```

Comment: Hmm, I tried this before, but it is still giving me the same error

Comment: Passing the function reference is fine.  Besides, your example will fail differently since in your anonymous function you don't actually invoke the passed callback, i.e. missing parens.

Comment: I still get the same error. Here's how I'm invoking the Ajax function: `send_data(url, data, createMessage("success"), createErrorMessage("error"));`

Comment: can you provide a minimal and working snip of your code?